# Generic factory with unknown implementation classes

Tags: java, generics

Let's assume two interfaces:

```
public interface FruitHandler<T extends Fruit>
{
    setFruit(T fruit);
    T getFruit();
}

public interface Fruit
{
}
```

Now I want a factory to create `FruitHandlers` (e.g. `AppleHander`, `OrangeHandler`, ...), but the `FruitHandlerFactory` does not know neccessary about the implementing classes of both interfaces (like in [java parameterized generic static factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153767)). The `FruitHandlerFactory` should work in this way (where `OrangeHandler` implements `FruitHandler` and `Orange` implements `Fruit`):

```
FruitHandlerFactory fhf = new FruitHandlerFactory<OrangeHandler,Orange>();
OrangeHandler fh = fhf.create();
Orange orange = (Orange)fh.getFruit();
```

This should be the factory:

```
public class FruitHandlerFactory<A extends FruitHandler, B extends Fruit>
{
    public FruitHandler create()
    {
        FruitHandler<Fruit> fh = new A<B>();   //<--- ERROR
        fh.setFruit(new B());
        return fh;
    }
}
```

Where I get this error:

```
The type A is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <B>
```

BTW: Is it possible to make the `create()` method static?

Comment: Excellent question, and great code snippet to illustrate.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since generics in Java are implemented using erasure, the type information of `FruitHandlerFactory` will not be available at runtime, which means you can't instantiate `A` (or `B`) this way.

You *can*, however pass in a `Class` object of the correct type to work around this:

```
public class FruitHandlerFactory<H extends FruitHandler<F>, F extends Fruit> {
    final Class<H> handlerClass;
    final Class<F> fruitClass;

    public FruitHandlerFactory(final Class<H> handlerClass, final Class<F> fruitClass) {
        this.handlerClass = handlerClass;
        this.fruitClass = fruitClass;
    }

    public H create() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        H handler = handlerClass.newInstance();
        handler.setFruit(fruitClass.newInstance());
        return handler;
    }
}
```

A minor drawback is that you'll have to write the type names three times(1) if you want to instantiate a `FruitHandlerFactory`:

```
FruitHandlerFactory fhf = new FruitHandlerFactory<OrangeHandler,Orange>(OrangeHandler.class, Orange.class);
```

You can somewhat reduce that by producing a `static` `createFactory()` method on your `FruitHandlerFactory`:

```
static <H extends FruitHandler<F>, F extends Fruit> FruitHandlerFactory<H, F> createFactory(
        final Class<H> handlerClass, final Class<F> fruitClass) {
    return new FruitHandlerFactory<H, F>(handlerClass, fruitClass);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
FruitHandlerFactory fhf = FruitHandlerFactory.createFactory(OrangeHandler.class, Orange.class);
```

Comment: in this method you need a public zero arguments constructor. any solution when the obect should have only private constructors?

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4452158/338803):

Perhaps try this?

```
public class FruitHandlerFactory<A extends FruitHandler<B>, B extends Fruit>
```