# Java8 Supplier interface to provide the proper typed instance

Tags: java, generics

How can I use Java8 Supplier interface to rewrite this factory method to provide the proper typed instance?

I've a simple interface that extends Map:

```
public interface Thingy<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {}
```

Then I have a ThingyFactory class, which contains a list of all of the implementation classnames of Thingy:

```
public final class ThingyFactory {
    Map<String, Class<Thingy<?, ?>>> thingyclasses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    .....

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <K, V> Thingy<K, V> getInstance(String classname) throws ThingyException {
        Thingy<K, V> thingy;
        try {
            thingy = (Thingy<K, V>) thingyclasses.get(classname).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new ThingyException("Something bad happened: ", e.toString());
        }
        return thingy;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I can do this elegantly and w/o the SuppressWarnings and classloader using the Supplier interface but I can't seem to get the pattern quite right. Any guidance appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question buddy.  Perhaps this might be useful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093363/generic-factory-with-unknown-implementation-classes

Comment: Should `thingyclasses` be `providers`?

Comment: Yes Jacob G i'll fix the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using wildcards as the generic type of `Thingy` within `thingyclasses`, you're essentially saying: *The types of `Thingy` can be anything*; however, this prohibits the compiler from inferring anything about the type, hence why you require an explicit cast.  You can use `Supplier` to improve it slightly, but you'll still have the warning regarding an unchecked cast:

```
class ThingyFactory {
    private Map<String, Supplier<Thingy<?, ?>>> providers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <K, V> Supplier<Thingy<K, V>> getInstance(String classname) {
        return () -> (Thingy<K, V>) providers.get(classname);
    }
}
```

If you want it to be type-safe, you'll need to redesign it entirely and only use wildcards if the compiler is able to infer the type(s).

Comment: Wildcards have nothing to do with type inference.

Comment: Hi Jacob - let me try another approach - forget the "providers" map completely - if I simply have the String classname, is there a way I can create a new instance of classname Thingy<K,V>?

Comment: @RichardSand Without an explicit cast to `Thingy<K, V>`, I doubt it, as your method isn't type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting challenge. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThingyFactory<String, String> factory = new ThingyFactory<>();
        Thingy<String, String> instance = factory.getInstance("ThingyImpl");
        System.out.println(instance.clazzName());
        Thingy<String, String> otherInstance = factory.getInstance(ThingyImpl.class);
        System.out.println(instance.clazzName());
    }
}

interface Thingy<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
    //added this method for testing purpuses
    String clazzName();
}

//extending HashMap so I don't have to implement Map's methods
class ThingyImpl<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> implements Thingy<K, V> {
    public String clazzName() {
        return "ThingyImpl";
    }
}

final class ThingyFactory<K, V> {
    private Map<String, Supplier<Thingy<K, V>>> providers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public ThingyFactory() {
        providers.put("ThingyImpl", () -> new ThingyImpl());
    }

    public Thingy<K, V> getInstance(String classname) {
        return providers.get(classname).get();
    }

    // alternative with Class. 
    // You could change providers to a Map<Class<? extends Thingy>, Supplier<Thingy<K, V>>>
    public Thingy<K, V> getInstance(Class<? extends Thingy> clazz) {
        return providers.get(clazz.getName()).get();
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need a ThingyFactory for every specific K, V type pair, but this is type safe.