# generic type instantiation java

Tags: java, generics

So I have this problem that I want to have a factory / manager class UserManager that manages Users. And Users have both UserType1 and UserType2 extending to it.

currently I have this for UserManager.

```
public abstract class UserManager<T extends User> {
    // T is either UserType1 or UserType2
    public ArrayList<T> users;
}
```

Now I want to create UserType1 or UserType2 depending on conditions, e.g.

```
public T create(boolean isType1) {
    if(isType1) // create UserType1
    else // create UserType2
}
```

And I can't just do

```
T newUser = new T();
```

I'm stuck, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: It seems you can always replace T by User, don't need generic here

Comment: Maybe related to of [Generic factory with unknown implementation classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093363/generic-factory-with-unknown-implementation-classes)

Answer (score 0):

```
public T create(boolean isType1) {
    if(isType1) // create UserType1
    else // create UserType2
}
```

This doesn't make sense: what happens if `T` is `UserType1` and `isType1` is false? Then you would create a `UserType2` which isn't a `T`.

If `isType1` is fixed for a given `UserManager` then it shouldn't be a parameter in the first place, and you can have

```
abstract public T create();
```

with different implementations or cheat with casts (bad idea, generally speaking).

Comment: UserType2 also extends User. Since T extends User, UserType2 could be a T right?

Comment: No. Think this way: inside `UserManager` `T` is some fixed type extending `User`, but you don't know which: it could be `UserType1`, `User`, some other subclass you don't know about, etc. Your code must make sense for any of those possible `T`s. So the problem is that `UserType2` could be _not_-a-`T`.