# Generic factory function for generic type

Tags: java, generics, factory-method

I'm aware this question is very similar, but not quite, to 
[java parameterized generic static factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153767/java-parameterized-generic-static-factory) .

So far I haven't found this exact case and can't figure out if what I want to do can even be done. So, suppose this almost minimal example:

```
public class Test {
  public static interface Interface<T, P> {
    T get(P param);
  }

  public static class StringIntInterface implements Interface<String, Integer> {
    public String get(Integer param) {
      String[] options = new String[] { "hello", "cruel", "world" };
      int p = param > 0 ? param : -param;
      return options[p % 3];
    }
  }

  public static class IntStringInterface implements Interface<Integer, String> { 
    public Integer get(String param) {
      return param.length();
    }
  }

  public static class InterfaceProvider {
    public Interface<?, ?> getInterface(String name) {
      if (name.equals("int")) {
        return new StringIntInterface();
      } else if (name.equals("string")) {
        return new IntStringInterface();
      }
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    InterfaceProvider ip = new InterfaceProvider();
    StringIntInterface si = (StringIntInterface)ip.getInterface("int");
    IntStringInterface is = (IntStringInterface)ip.getInterface("string");
    System.out.println(si.get(5));
    System.out.println(is.get("a somewhat long string, whatever"));
  }
}
```

This is the only version I got to compile and work as expected so far, also, interestingly (to me) without unchecked conversion warnings...

I guess it's clear what I'd like to do here, but is there a way to get rid of the casts in the usages of `InterfaceProvider::getInterface()` within `Test::main()`? I've tried various ways to make `InterfaceProvider::getInterface()` a generic method, all of which lead to compile errors. Those tried signatures so far were:

```
public <R, P, T extends Interface<R, P>> T getInterface(String name);
public <R, P, T extends Interface<R, P>> T getInterface(String name, Class<R> retType, Class<P> paramType);
public <T extends Interface<?, ?>> T getInterface(String name);
```

since I want the parameters `T` and `P` of `Interface` to be without any bounds whatsoever, and want to only have to instantiate one InterfaceProvider for whatever implementations of `Interface` I don't have the option to move any of the type parameters to the InterfaceProvider class...

Any ideas? Or is that simply impossible?

Comment: Have you thought about having 2 separate methods on `InterfaceProvider`, 1 for each interface?

Comment: That’s sadly not an option. I face this problem coding a system where the implementation of Interface is provided by the user at runtime, loaded dynamically by class name. T and P will most likely end up being provided the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `StringIntInterface` or `IntStringInterface` in `main`. Interface is to define a specification to let user don't need to care about implemetations. If you need to know the specific implementation `StringIntInterface`, why you need the factory? So it should be

```
Interface<String, Integer> si = (Interface<String, Integer>) ip.getInterface("int");
Interface<Integer, String> is = (Interface<Integer, String>)ip.getInterface("string");
```

Now all of you attempted signature will work

```
public <R, P, T extends Interface<R, P>> T getInterface(String name);
Interface<String, Integer> si = ip.getInterface("int");
Interface<Integer, String> is = ip.getInterface("string");
```

But note, though it works (that you don't need to do explicit cast), every thing not change. It is still not type safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly, it doesn't work. The error returned by javac: Test.java:23: error: incompatible types: StringIntInterface cannot be converted to T
        return new StringIntInterface();
               ^
same for the line 25 (`new IntStringInterface()`)

Comment: @tjanu Please add `(T)` when return, `return (T) new IntStringInterface();`.

Comment: thanks, that does fix it and is typesafe enough for my needs (throws a ClassCastException when I swap the return statements within `InterfaceProvider::getInterface()`), which is all the "security" I need in this regard. Of course, the unchecked cast is kind of ugly, but I guess in this case it can't be helped.

Comment: @tjanu If it really resolve your question, please accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, simply forgot